# sizeof class inside a member function of that class

Tags: visual-c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Myclass 
{
public:
    void Displaysize()
    {
        cout<<sizeof(Myclass);
    }
private:
    int x, y, z;
};
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 Myclass Ob;
  Ob.Displaysize();
    return 0;
}
```

When I execute this I got the size of class as 12, which is correct, how compiler come to now the size of the class properly. I read in Geeks for Geeks as follows "If a non-static object is member then declaration of class is incomplete and compiler has no way to find out size of the objects of the class."
Could some one answer my query.

Comment: The class is considered complete within the method definition, even if that definition is physically in-class. The compiler behaves as if the method definition were moved out of class. Thus, you can access `x`, `y` and `z` within `Displaysize`.